# Passing Routerlink to child component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I create a component in my shared module, it is header component so in all of my components I want to call this.

In my shared component, let call it app-header component, I want to accept input Title: string, buttonName: string and buttonLink: any (since I am confused)
my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-header',
  templateUrl: './app-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-header.component.less']
})
export class AppHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() buttonName: string; 
    @Input() buttonLink: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

my app.header.html

```
<div class='row border-bottom my-4 align-middle apptitle'>
    <div class="col-8 my-2">
      <div>
        <h3> {{title}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 my-2 text-right">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [routerLink]={{buttonLink}}>{{buttonName}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I pass use this component in my other component :

my shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedComponent } from './shared.component';
import { AppHeaderComponent } from './app-header/app-header.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [
      SharedComponent, 
    AppHeaderComponent],
  exports:[
      AppHeaderComponent,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

My problem is I don't know how to pass the link so the routerlink will work.
Any idea how to pass the link / router link in proper way ? the routes belong to the component's module who call it.

I have many lazy loaded modules which will use this shared component. So I guess the route should be able to redirect/call link from its caller component module.

Edited: add more information

Shared Module : AppHeaderComponent  (this has no Routes)

AdminModule: AdminComponent -> call AppHeaderComponent inside (AdminModule has Routes)

UserMoudule: UserComponent -> call AppHeaderComponent inside (UserModule has Routes)

I need AppHeaderComponent to link to correct routeLink.

Example:
in UserComponent:

```
<app-app-header
    [title]= "'Users'"
    [buttonName]="'Create New'"
    [buttonLink]="['/user/create']"
></app-app-header>
```

Comment: Are you going to have just one link in your `HeaderComponent`? Or is this `HeaderLinkComponent` that you're trying to create here? And you want to create multiple of these using the `HeaderComponent` itself?

Comment: Please also add the implementation of how exactly are you using the `AppHeaderComponent` in the template.

Comment: I add the usage above. User in UserModule, while AppHeaderComponent in SharedModule.

Answer (score 1):

To make routing work in your `SharedModule`, you'll also have to add the `RouterModule` to your `imports` array.

```
...
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Also, in your `HeaderComponent`, you'll need to fix the `routerLink` assignment:

```
...
<button 
  class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
  [routerLink]="buttonLink">
  {{buttonName}}
</button>
...
```

And you should be using this component like this(WITHOUT `[]`):

```
<app-app-header 
  [title]="'Organisations'" 
  [buttonName]="'Create New'" 
  [buttonLink]="'/admin/user/create'">
</app-app-header>
```

Comment: I add the usage above. User in UserModule, while AppHeaderComponent in SharedModule.
so if I call /admin/user/create in AppHeaderComponent it will redirect to home or / since it doesn't know the routes. Routes is in User Module.

Comment: yes i am using lazy loading modules. 
the Admin/User module has routes. it works. but I need to call those routes from my SharedModule component.

I create app header component just for simplicity of my app.

Comment: Ok I will explain: I want all my components has the same header, so if someday the client want to change the header, it will be implemented on all components.

but in there there is a button the Create New Data. For example: User => Create New User (UserModules has routes for user/create, but shared module didn't know about it right).

Comment: I get that. But my question is, why pass the links and the link texts as `@Input` properties. If you pass these, and there are multiple links, then you're also not doing an `*ngFor` to loop through these links while rendering them on the template. So why not simply hardcode them in your HeaderComponent Template?

Comment: Unless you share your Router Config implementation, it would be hard to understand why the routeLink is taking the user to `/home` or `/` instead of the specified path. It has nothing to do with whether some modules have routes and some don't. It also has nothing to do with your SharedModule containing no `routes` whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a little bit change your code. You need to pass your link by using another construction.  [routerLink]="buttonLink".

More about template expression and interpolation you can read on [official documentation of angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Comment: hmm but i think it still will not work because this module has no routes. while the calller component in different module (it has routes)